# Ajax and Highcharts - Display 'loading' until data is retrieved, then populate chart

Tags: ajax, highcharts

I have some php scripts which esentially take a long time to retrieve data. As a result this impacts highcharts loading times as the current code I have only writes the chart once all the data is retrieved as the highcharts code is only echoed once all processing is complete.

This causes the page to basically show nothing until the data is retrieved. The goal is to have the highcharts load immedietly and then write to the series with the data returned by the php scripts.

So, what I'm looking to to is have all the graphs load immedietly and display 'loading' with no data and then use setData to pass in the data to the graph series once the php scripts have completed.

I'm just wondering if anyone had any examples of this being done? Another problem I'm having is only being able to set the data within the $(document).ready(function() function. e.g.

works: 
    http://preview.tinyurl.com/b724bxo

breaks: 
    http://preview.tinyurl.com/a7mqqkc

Many thanks and any help would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access variable out of scope, move that into that scope, or make variable global.

- http://jsfiddle.net/M2jv7/33/ -inside scope
- http://jsfiddle.net/M2jv7/34/ -global variable

  ```
  var pipeline_by_sales_stage_highchart;
  $(document).ready(function () {
              pipeline_by_sales_stage_highchart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  });

  ...

  // somewhere:
  pipeline_by_sales_stage_highchart.series[0].setData(data);
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pawel. I tried your global variable example, however it seems to work great in jsfiddle but the object goes out of scope when trying it locally on my machine:
"Error: TypeError: pipeline_by_sales_stage_highchart is undefined"

Comment: Maybe you have twice $().ready? Make sure that variable is global. For example in Chrome open console, type pipeline_....highchart and see if is defined.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know if you're still looking for this, but to display a "loading" message, you can use the "setLoading()" method on the chart.

```
pipeline_by_sales_stage_highchart.setLoading("Loading...")
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QSfEJ/

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't contain setLoading()

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here: [Highchart series update in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407901/highchart-series-update-in-javascript/39353204#39353204)

---

Summary :

Initialise chart with empty series, then use `addSeries` in a loop to update chart, like this:

```
this.dataFromApi.forEach(function(serie) { // for each row of data, add a series
  this.chart.addSeries(serie, false); // false is to prevent redrawing
}.bind(this));
this.chart.redraw(); // manually redraw
this.chart.hideLoading(); // stop loading if showLoading() was call before
```

jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qyh81spb/