# Want to get data from database in html javascript chart for asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net, highcharts

i have created a simple chart by using HighChart please give me some suggestions and guide how can i get value from database

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Chartz.aspx.cs" Inherits="Chartz" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>   
   <script>
       $(function () {
           $('#container').highcharts({
               chart: {
                   type: 'pie',
                   options3d: {
                       enabled: true,
                       alpha: 45,
                       beta: 0
                   }
               },
               title: {
                   text: 'Medicine market shares  2016'
               },
               tooltip: {
                   pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
               },
               plotOptions: {
                   pie: {
                       allowPointSelect: true,
                       cursor: 'pointer',
                       depth: 35,
                       dataLabels: {
                           enabled: true,
                           format: '{point.name}'
                       }
                   }
               },
               series: [{
                   type: 'pie',
                   name: 'Medicine share',
                   data: [
                       ['Epilepsy medicines', 45.0],
                       ['Biological medicines ', 26.8],
                       {
                           name: 'Ciclosporin ',
                           y: 12.8,
                           sliced: true,
                           selected: true
                       },
                       ['Mesalazine ', 8.5],
                       ['Lithium ', 6.2],
                       ['Others', 0.7]
                   ]
               }]
           });
       });
   </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
     <div class="row col-md-offset-1" data-spy="scroll" style="padding:80px 0px 0px 10px;" >
         <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
     </div>
</asp:Content>
```

i want to get value from database its working now and i have hard coded value please give me guide or reference link 
Help in advance

Comment: If the data is (as I suspect) the `series` attribute, then you can change it to `series: <%= GetData() %>` and create a protected function in the code behind called, `GetData()`, that returns a string.  Get the data from your database and build the string as required by HighChart .

Comment: i am trying to implement through web method and with json (data is now retrieved) but problem is now how to interact this with HighChart to show my relevent data on Highchart?

Comment: I'm not marking this as a duplicate to be closed, as this link only answers part of your question.  You'll need to look at getting the data via a webmethod in order to expand on this...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407901/highchart-series-update-in-javascript  If you can post code to show your existing webmethod then that will help us help you.

Comment: o.k thanks i have to implement it in my code first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set data: <%=chartData%> and get the data from database and deserialize it to show in charts.

refer this [link](http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/steps-to-implement-highcharts-reports-in-dot-net-application/2/) .

Comment: Thanks this link help me a lot and i have found my solution