# How to update series data array in highcharts

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I have the following snippet of code which updates my chart type from one type to another.

```
             chart.series.forEach(function(serie){
                    serie.update({
                        type: type,
                        stacking: stacking,
                    })
                })
```

I can pass different values in from type to stacking.
If I want my new chart to use a different array of values, the arrays of which are already defined and contain data from the database; how would I do it?

The reason I wish to do this is because I have two values, which are entered in their own arrays, say for example, 40 and 50 from a database. These are then stacked in a column chart (It's the only way I can stack).

I've created another array to store both these values in the one array when deciding to show it in a pie chart (not stacked).

I've tried adding 'data:arrayName' in as a property but this prevents my chart from rendering. Any idea guys?

Thank you.

EDIT: My problem probably only required one object to call. I don't have that much going on so the solution in the possible duplicate isn't really helpful to me. The duplicate code is trying to generate a new array on the fly using loops, I already have an array in place, I'm just figuring out how to update the array once the chart has changed to another type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highchart series update in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407901/highchart-series-update-in-javascript)

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle, or post the rest of your code/data?