# Highcharts adding new data points in VueJS / Vuex

Tags: highcharts, vuejs2

I want to use highcharts to display an initial set of data and then every two seconds add a new data point. 
I am subscribing to an external WebSocket services that initially provides me with the data and then sends me a new value every two seconds.

I am using the events option in Highcharts to try and get the data out of the vuex store. Here is my code.

```
chart:{
                  type: 'spline',
                  animation: '',
                  events: {
                    load: function () {

                      // set up the updating of the chart each second
                      var series = this.series[0];
                      setInterval(function () {

                        series.addPoint([this.$store.getters.getTickEpoch, this.$store.getters.getTickQuote], true, true);
                      }.bind(this), 1000);
                    }.bind(this)
                  }
                }
```

The problem is that if I don't add .bind(this) to my functions, I can't see the vuex store, but when I do add .bind(this) then var series = this.series[0]; no longer works.

How do I use vuex data to update my chart in real time?

Comment: have idea from this [post] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39353204/3898339).

Comment: `Highcharts.charts` is an array of all charts on the page. If you only have one chart on the page then the series you need is `Highcharts.charts[0].series[0]`.

Comment: Solution proposed by @Dmitry works: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/ucvoamnr/ `chart` variable is still not defined when the `load` event fires but the chart is already saved in `Highcharts.charts` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use the [vue-highcharts](https://github.com/weizhenye/vue-highcharts) plugin. This resolved all my problems and allowed me to very quickly setup a real time chart by following the simple examples.

Comment: Where are you seeing examples using vue.highcharts or some documentation?