# Adding additional data to chart

Tags: javascript, dynamic, chart.js

I am trying to add some data to a chart created with chart.js.

I get "undefined" as an error. How do I add data into this? Looks like a stupid silly newbie error...please bear with me and help. Thanks

```js
var birdsCanvas = document.getElementById("birdsChart");

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;

var birdsData = {
    labels: ["Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"],
    datasets: [{
        //data: [1200, 1700, 800, 200],
        data: [5, 10, 3, 9],
        backgroundColor: [
            "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)",
            "rgba(0, 255,200, 0.6)",
            "rgba(200, 0, 200, 0.6)",
            "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.6)"
        ],
        borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)"
    }]
};

var chartOptions = {
    startAngle: -Math.PI / 4,
    legend: {
        position: 'left'
    },
    animation: {
        animateRotate: false
    }
};

var polarAreaChart = new Chart(birdsCanvas, {
    type: 'polarArea',
    data: birdsData,
    options: chartOptions
});

//alert ('checking value... birdsData label 1 ' + birdsData.labels[1]);

polarAreaChart.birdsData.datasets.push({
    label: 'label2',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)',
    data: [9]
});
barChart.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="birdsChart" width="600" height="550"></canvas>
```

I get TypeError: polarAreaChart.birdsData is undefined .. I just want to add data dynamically through functions when users click on something..

Thanks

Comment: [Highchart series update in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407901/highchart-series-update-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `polarAreaChart.data.datasets.push({` instead of `birdsData` as there is no `bridsData` object in the chart object:

```js
var birdsCanvas = document.getElementById("birdsChart");

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;

var birdsData = {
  labels: ["Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"],
  datasets: [{
    //data: [1200, 1700, 800, 200],
    data: [5, 10, 3, 9],
    backgroundColor: [
      "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)",
      "rgba(0, 255,200, 0.6)",
      "rgba(200, 0, 200, 0.6)",
      "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.6)"
    ],
    borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)"
  }]
};

var chartOptions = {
  startAngle: -Math.PI / 4,
  legend: {
    position: 'left'
  },
  animation: {
    animateRotate: false
  }
};

var polarAreaChart = new Chart(birdsCanvas, {
  type: 'polarArea',
  data: birdsData,
  options: chartOptions
});

//alert ('checking value... birdsData label 1 ' + birdsData.labels[1]);

polarAreaChart.data.datasets.push({
  label: 'label2',
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)',
  borderColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)',
  data: [9]
});
polarAreaChart.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="birdsChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: I added and did the changes... and no error in console on firefox but the label and data isn't added :-(

Comment: I fixed it... by instructions mentioned at https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html but need to figure out how to add background color to a new item

Comment: @Rajan that's great, for color won't `backgroundColor` do the trcik?

Comment: Yes. done! One needs to pass the backgroundColor as an array item for either all the labels or just for the label to change, with other items in the array being blank.